# How to tell systemd to start sshd later in the boot sequence?

Tags: centos, systemd, sshd

My sshd_config file specifies it should listen on some specific IP addresses instead of on all IP addresses.  The problem is that one of these NICs doesn't come up until later in the boot sequence.  By then sshd has started and, since the IP address wasn't available, never listens on that IP address.

```
ListenAddress 127.0.0.1
ListenAddress 10.0.0.10
```

Is there a way to tell sshd to re-scan for available IP addresses periodically or is there a way to tell systemd to start sshd later?

Comment: What distribution are you using? Debian and derivatives have a `/etc/network/if-up.d/openssh-server` script which restarts the SSH server when an interface comes up...

Comment: Are you able, in your environment, to use systemd socket activation for your sshd's? If so, you can use systemd's nifty FREEBIND option to bind to an address before a network interface with that address has come up.

Comment: Centos7.  Oddly enough another machine with the same configuration isn't having this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Services launched by systemd at boot are ordered by dependencies. To tell systemd to launch the `sshd.service` unit *later*, you have to tell it which unit it should *wait for* before starting the service.

Once you have found the unit responsible for the network setup (most probably `network.service` on CentOS 7), you can create a drop-in configuration file (the name must be `something`**.conf**) in the folder `/etc/systemd/system/sshd.service.d/` (may not exist initially) with the following content:

```
[Unit]
After=network.service
Requires=network.service
```

This will inform systemd that it needs to wait for the startup of the service `network.service` to finish before launching `sshd.service`.

If you are using [systemd-networkd](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-networkd.html), you may use [systemd-networkd-wait-online](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-networkd-wait-online.html) to wait for the setup of a specific interface using `--interface=eth0`.

Comment: does systemd have a concept more granular than "network is ready"? For example, specific interfaces

Comment: It does not have such concepts built-in: systemd does not understand network readiness on purpose. You should create a new target or service doing the specific setup you need for your interface and order other units after this service is started or target is reached.

Comment: If you use [systemd-networkd](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-networkd.html), you may use [systemd-networkd-wait-online](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-networkd-wait-online.html) to wait for the setup of a specific interface using `--interface=eth0`.